# OAuth authentication is failing due to invalid_grant

Tags: oauth2

Our application is integrating with Salesforce using OAuth for the past 2 years.
Suddenly since yesterday, we are unable to connect new instances using OAuth.

Authentication on the client-side is working ok (we get the code parameter) but it fails when generating the access token against Salesforce API (/services/oauth2/token)

The error we receive -

> {
> "error": "invalid_grant",
> "error_description": "expired access/refresh token"
> }

The weird part is that everything works great in our TEST environment but doesn't work in our PROD environment. This means we are able to connect new integrations from a specific environment only.

We use the same App for both environments so the client id is the same.

Comment: How is your Connected App defined in terms of OAuth scopes?

Comment: @cropredy, there are no scopes in the oauth request. here is the URL -
login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=${state}

Comment: I was asking about the Oauth scopes defined in Setup | Connected Apps.    Specifically whether refresh_token is included.

Comment: @cropredy Yes, refresh_token is included. The list is: Access your basic information (id, profile, email, address, phone);
Access and manage your data (API) ; Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)

Comment: @AvivKebab Can you walk us through the flow? First of all, I assume you're using the web-server flow, based on the fact that you're first getting the authorization code, then sending that to the token endpoint.

Second, your URL for the authorization code seems to be correct, and you're getting the code back, so all is well.

Lastly, I would like to know: what is the URL you're using for the token endpoint? Are you passing in the client secret? Have you checked the client secret hasn't changed from one environment to the other?